# Activeadmin assets loading in every non admin page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am running in an issue setting up the `activeadmin` gem. It's running fine but the issue is that it's loading the assets required from `activeadmin` in my main layout view. I wonder how to make it import the CSS and JS files to the view only when accessing the **admin** path.

In advance thanks for the help

- application.html.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render "shared/main_nav" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

- application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

there is also an `active_admin.scss` file in the same path of the `application.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The require_tree directive in a CSS manifest is requiring all stylesheets from the current directory.

So you can remove the require_tree and include only the files you want.